# Grabbing multiple rows within nested JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have json data that flows into a database. The data is always changing and increasing in size so I need to account for that. 
There is some data I need to grab that is nested inside an array. Here is a small snippet of the json:

```
"code":3,
"data":[
    {
        "evaluator_id":"1",
        "subject":{
            "lastName":"John",
            "firstName":"Smith",
        },
        "data":{
            "task1Data":[
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":11,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":10,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":9,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":8,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":7,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":6,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":5,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":4,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":3,
                },
                {
                    "fixedObjectsPresented":2,
                }
            ]
        },
        "organization":"Tester",
        "evaluator":"Tester1"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to grab the fixedObjectsPresented field, which I can do successfully. The issue is that it only grabs the first row for each user I create. 
In this case there are 10 rows, so 10 rows for each user should be created in the database table. Right now it only grabs the first row for each user I have.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    // connect to the database
    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("Test", $con);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

    // read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('hidden.json');

    // convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    $count=0;

    foreach($data['data'] as $row) {

        // set the variables

        $task = $row['data']['task1Data'];

        // able to grab any single row with [0], but need to grab all rows
        $fixedObjectsPresented      = $task['fixedObjectsPresented'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO example(fixedObjectsPresented)
        VALUES('$fixedObjectsPresented')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fixedObjectsPresented = fixedObjectsPresented";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result) {
        $count++;
     }
     // todo change to !result when fixed
    else if($result){
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
     }

    }

    return $count;

?>
```

I've also tried a nested foreach statement but I got the same result. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to loop over your $task array. See below code:

```
// connect to the database
  $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("Test", $con);
  mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

  // read the json file contents
  $jsondata = file_get_contents('hidden.json');

  // convert json object to php associative array
  $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

  $count=0;

  echo "<pre>";

  foreach($data['data'] as $row) {

    // set the variables
    $task = $row['data']['task1Data'];

    if (count($task)) {
      foreach($task as $subtask) {

        $fixedObjectsPresented      = $subtask['fixedObjectsPresented'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO example(fixedObjectsPresented)
        VALUES('$fixedObjectsPresented')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fixedObjectsPresented = fixedObjectsPresented";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

      if($result) {
          $count++;
      }
      // todo change to !result when fixed
      else if($result) {
          die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($task as $fixedObjectsPresented) {
      // able to grab any single row with [0], but need to grab all rows

      $sql = "INSERT INTO example(fixedObjectsPresented)
      VALUES('$fixedObjectsPresented')
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fixedObjectsPresented = fixedObjectsPresented";

      $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working ,but your logic is a little wrong here

```
foreach($data['data'] as $row) {

    // set the variables

    $task = $row['data']['task1Data'];//that will get in Array

    //foreach will able to grab any single row with [0] of all rows
   foreach ($tab as $key => $value) {
      $fixedObjectsPresented = $tab[$key]['fixedObjectsPresented'];

      $sql = "INSERT INTO example(fixedObjectsPresented)
      VALUES('$fixedObjectsPresented')
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fixedObjectsPresented = fixedObjectsPresented";

      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      if($result) {
      $count++;
      }
     // todo change to !result when fixed
     else if($result){
     die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
     }
   }


}
```